# Where is uninstalled plugin tab in Plugin window of QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2.18, mmqgis

I was trying to install mmqgis plugin for QGIS 2.18. However, i cannot see the 'uninstalled' tab in the plugin window. I need help on:

1. how to fix this issue?
2. how to install MMQGIS plugin?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Menu Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...

In the *Plugins* window you will see the *Not Installed* tab on the left hand side (see image below).

Then search for "mmqgis".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to internet, you can search for mmqgis plugin and install it. Without accessing internet you cannot install the plugin.

Now you are mixing uninstall with Not install (maybe). `Uninstall` appears if you click on any installed plugin and you need to remove it as shown below:

[image]

`Not install` appears on the left side menu for the plugins that are not installed in your QGIS, if you have access to the internet.